# extracting values from a list created by split() function

Tags: r, list, split, extract

I have a list of the form below, about 1400 characters. I would like to extract the values from each date/time in order to plot them.

```
$`2012-07-19 22:30:00`
[1] NaN

$`2012-07-19 23:00:00`
[1] 23.91

$`2012-07-19 23:30:00`
[1] 23.83286
```

I've tried several different forms of the sapply function that I found online but each time I get the same list (below) which I haven't been able to plot. If I can extract these values I should be able to use na.omit to remove the 'NaN'. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
2012-07-19 22:30:00 2012-07-19 23:00:00 2012-07-19 23:30:00 
                NaN            23.91000            23.83286
```

In addition does anyone know how to find how many values are present in the list for each date?
I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by copy/pasting some of your data ? You can use `dput(head())` for this.

Comment: you've only one value per element of the list. Why not just wrap it with `as.data.frame(.)` or simply `unlist`?

Comment: You tried `unlist()` and `length()`? And why you can't plot (which error message is printed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few options:

- **stack** (works with unequal elements within list as well)

  ```
  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
  stack(L)
  #   values ind
  # 1      1   a
  # 2      2   b
  # 3      3   c

  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=c(3,4))
  stack(L)
  #   values ind
  # 1      1   a
  # 2      2   b
  # 3      3   c
  # 4      4   c
  ```

To plot just the values, you can just do `plot(stack(L)$values)`

- **unlist** (works with unequal list elements as well, names are changed accordingly)

  ```
  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
  unlist(L)
  # a b c 
  # 1 2 3 

  unname(unlist(L))            ## using unname to remove the names
  # 1 2 3 

  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=c(3,4))
  unlist(L)
  # a b c1 c2                  ## note the automatic name assignment here
  # 1 2  3  4
  ```

To plot, you can just do: `plot(unlist(L))` (or) equivalently `plot(unname(unlist(L)))`

- **as.data.frame** (with unequal elements, values get **recycled**, careful!). This is not useful (at least not straightforward if you've to plot, as in your case) here that much.

  ```
  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=3)
  as.data.frame(L)
  #   a b c
  # 1 1 2 3

  L <- list(a=1, b=2, c=c(3,4))
  as.data.frame(L)
  #   a b c
  # 1 1 2 3
  # 1 1 2 4
  ```